# Bad operand types for binary operator. Why doesn't this work?

Tags: java

I'm confused why this doesn't work. It's suppose to set all the table[count] to null but it wont let me.

```
public HashTable(int sz) {

    // Count to initalize all to null
    int counter = 0;

    // Initalizes the global size to the
    // sz passed in
    size = sz;

    // Initalizes
    table = new Base[size];
    probeCount = new int[size];

    // Initalizes all to null
    while (counter <= probeCount) {
        table[count] = null;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `counter` and what is `probeCount`?

Comment: Also, you may want to use `table[counter]`, or you will just set one element at index `count` to null, instead of all. And do `<` instead of `<=` or you will run into an `ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsException`.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want to do. You're comparing two different things. You want to compare the size

```
        // Initalizes all to null
        while (counter <= size)/ {

            table[count] = null;
            counter++;
        }
```

Comment: I would say `counter < size`, instead of `counter <= size`.